# Reverting a Merge TFS 2015

Tags: tfs, merge, tfs-2015, revert

I have two branches say Branch Child and Parent.
Changesets in Branch Child : 200,201,202,203,204(contain .Net and VB codes)
I have merged up from child to parent containing all these changeset and TFS2015 gives me a changeset number for parent Branch as 300.

Now later i decide that changeset number 201,202 is not required for Branch Parent for now(will be used  later)

Is there any way to roll back only changes pertaining to 201,202 from Parent Branch?

What i have tried : i tried rolling back the entire change set number 300. I get error message that revert failed due to dependency on other applications. I am not sure why this error is occurring.

Comment: That's a strange error. Can you share the exact error message? Did you have a solution open when doing the merge? These kinds of rollbacks are best done from a commandline with all solutions closed. You may need to undo pending changes on the server and/or revert existing locks on files as well.

Comment: Yes, please share the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Rollback Command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380776.aspx) to see whether you can revert the changeset:

```
tf rollback /changeset:C300
```